# How to find contents of missed revisions in SVN?

Tags: svn

I have two branches  for which the merge was done using STS. Now we found out that there are is some content which was not merged.
So we find the missing revisions using this command

svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible http://mybase.branch.1 http://mytrunk.branch

I get a list of revisions. Now I would like to see the content which was not merged excluding certain files like pom.xml , properties file.

svn diff is not able to help out.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new and clean checkout of the branch. Merge all changes from the trunk on this branch. Do not commit anything! Revert files you are not interested in. Examine the changes in the working directory. Example:

```
svn checkout http://svn.example.org/svn/foobar/branches/0.42 foobar
cd foobar
svn merge ^/trunk
```

After these commands, the working directory contains all changes (uncommitted) that have not been merged onto the branch. You can use most SVN client to examine the changes - and revert some of them to ignore them.

You can do a lot of operations from the command line. The following command lines (bash, Linux) reverts all changes made to files named "pom.xml":

```
svn revert $( find -name pom.xml )
```

The following command line reverts all files except Java files (bash, Linux):

```
svn revert $( find -type f ! -name \*.java )
```

You can also use the command line tool to examine the remaining changes, e.g.:

```
svn status
svn diff
```

Comment: svn revert $( find -name pom.xml ) does not seem to work. I tried >svn revert -R pom.xml and it says "Skipped 'pom.xml' "

Comment: is there a way only to find difference for certain files for eg .java ?

Comment: The command line argument `$( find -name pom.xml )` is specific for bash (i.e. Linux). It will not work, if you are working with another shell or with another operating system. However, you can use almost any SVN client to examine the working directory and reverting some files.

Comment: Since I was in windows, it did not work exactly as you suggested. So i took the trunk and merged the missing revisions into trunk and then took the difference. Your answers helped me move in right direction